# How to assign a value to a session variable that changes depending on the selection of an image map

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to have a value added to a session variable depending on the choise a user makes. The user makes the choise by clicking inside some area shapes inside an image map.

This is the code I have.

```
<a class="selection_5M_platform"><img src="../../images/Selection/Windmillselection-platform5M-fullview.gif" usemap="#Windmillselection_Map5M_platform" alt="windmill_platform6M" name="windmill_platform6M">
    <map class="map" name="Windmillselection_Map5M_platform">          
      <area shape="poly" coords="12,131,56,131,61,133,68,136,74,140,74,345,12,345" href="../submitreport.php" onClick="<?php $_POST['selectedreportlocation']="5M_PLATFORM_LADDERS" ?>" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('windmill_platform6M','','../../images/Selection/Windmillselection-platform5M-ladders.gif',1)" alt="ladders_platform5M">                   
      <area shape="poly" coords="73,344,73,141,69,136,59,132,48,131,48,124,267,123,267,132,229,135,202,142,194,151,195,344" href="../submitreport.php" onClick="<?php $_SESSION['selectedreportlocation']="5M_PLATFORM_FOUNDATION" ?>" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('windmill_platform6M','','../../images/Selection/Windmillselection-platform5M-foundation.gif',1)" alt="foundation_platform5M">
      <area shape="poly" coords="148,121,177,121,177,46,125,6,47,6,47,74,58,74,58,46,105,52,109,67,121,67,126,54,148,58" href="../submitreport.php" onClick="<?php $_SESSION['selectedreportlocation']="5M_PLATFORM_PALFINGER" ?>" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('windmill_platform6M','','../../images/Selection/Windmillselection-platform5M-palfinger.gif',1)" alt="palfinger_platform5M">
      <area shape="poly" coords="49,123,49,92,149,92,149,121,177,121,177,91,187,62,271,60,268,90,268,123" href="../submitreport.php"  onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onClick="<?php $_SESSION['selectedreportlocation']="5M_PLATFORM_GUARDRAIL" ?>" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('windmill_platform6M','','../../images/Selection/Windmillselection-platform5M-guardrail.gif',1)" alt="guardrail_platform5M">          
    </map>        
</a>
```

The problem with this code: It doesn't mather which choise u make, it always stores the same value in the session variable (the last one "5M_PLATFORM_GUARDRAIL").

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, this is **not** how you can use PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make my answer helpful I suggest this solution:

Replace HTML-markup of your `<map>` with this:

```
<map class="map" name="Windmillselection_Map5M_platform">          
    <area shape="poly" coords="12,131,56,131,61,133,68,136,74,140,74,345,12,345" href="../submitreport.php?location=5M_PLATFORM_LADDERS" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('windmill_platform6M','','../../images/Selection/Windmillselection-platform5M-ladders.gif',1)" alt="ladders_platform5M">
    <area shape="poly" coords="73,344,73,141,69,136,59,132,48,131,48,124,267,123,267,132,229,135,202,142,194,151,195,344" href="../submitreport.php?location=5M_PLATFORM_FOUNDATION" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('windmill_platform6M','','../../images/Selection/Windmillselection-platform5M-foundation.gif',1)" alt="foundation_platform5M">
    <area shape="poly" coords="148,121,177,121,177,46,125,6,47,6,47,74,58,74,58,46,105,52,109,67,121,67,126,54,148,58" href="../submitreport.php?location=5M_PLATFORM_PALFINGER" ?>" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('windmill_platform6M','','../../images/Selection/Windmillselection-platform5M-palfinger.gif',1)" alt="palfinger_platform5M">
  <area shape="poly" coords="49,123,49,92,149,92,149,121,177,121,177,91,187,62,271,60,268,90,268,123" href="../submitreport.php?location=5M_PLATFORM_GUARDRAIL"  onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('windmill_platform6M','','../../images/Selection/Windmillselection-platform5M-guardrail.gif',1)" alt="guardrail_platform5M">          
</map>
```

in your `../submitreport.php` you should insert this block:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['selectedreportlocation'] = $_GET['location'];

// session variable will be available from now
```

P.S. You are completely misunderstanding the principles of server-side programming. You have to read some tutorials about PHP at first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't want to add all my code to this Q/A section because it would become unclear. Anyway.. I know the method you've provided works. Still I don't like information being passes by the url. The reason I was trying to use a session variable was to prevent the information from being visible in the url bar. It's a nice to have, not a need to have. And I agree that I still have to learn alot! Altough a solution that passes the info from the selection page to the submitreport.php page, without the use of the url/get method, would be great.

Comment: OK, there are two more methods: sending variable with POST-request and saving variable into cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing php code (server code) with javascript (client code). The server code is executed before the page is rendered. So your last line of php is the one that is executed.  Check the html source, you won't see the php code in it.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right! The reason this happens is because i've only started to program one month ago. I make many mistakes like this. Any advise on how to solve this would be awesome!